# Node.js Post method request not working {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, npm, hapi.js

I am fairly new to Node.js, I was using a tutorial from the page below.

http://www.9lessons.info/2017/02/create-restful-api-nodejs-mysql.html

Now the issue am having is with the post method.When I call any other then the Get methods I get this error:

https://github.com/srinivastamada/NodeRestful/blob/master/server.js

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/messages',

    handler: function (request, reply) {

        const uid = request.payload.uid;
        console.log(uid);

        connection.query('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE uid_fk = "' + uid + '"', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(results);
            reply(results);
        });
    },
    config: {
        validate: {
            payload: {
                uid: Joi.number().integer()
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Questions here about code must include the relevant code pasted into the question, not just available via an external link.  This is because external links have a habit of disappearing or changing over time making your question worthless for those who find it in the future.  Being a long term reference for Q&A questions about programming is an important objective for stack overflow.  So, please put the relevant code and error messages pasted directly into your question and formatted appropriately.

Comment: Also, we don't want a link to some tutorial you followed.  We want to see YOUR actual code.

Comment: @ZuluWar can you show us how you are hitting this POST api `/message`.

Comment: @ShubhamBatra ok am calling this route http://localhost:8000/messages. Can't post the how code snippet. That github link above is basically every I am using.

Comment: @ZuluWar you need to call this from Postman with valid parameters.

Comment: @ShubhamBatra  I tried including the {uid} on the message routine. Still not working. Can maybe give me a hint on how to go about doing this.

Comment: @ZuluWar If you try to hit any POST request from browser manually that always give you 404

Answer (score 0):

first you need to insert data into messages table.

then hit the post request from POSTMAN. see image below.

[image]